# Is there any equivalent to noise reduction in Gimp Python-fu?

Tags: filter, gimp, noise-reduction, python-fu

I am working to develop a Gimp plug-in to convert images to comics/manga using Python-Fu. The code is working quite well at the moment (I know AI can do the same but coding its own plug-in is free isn't?):

[image: Processing of the image by the Python-fu plug-in]

From what I understood Python-Fu is still in development (is it?) and there are not all the equivalent image manipulation tools as in the main software. In particular, I would be extremely interested to obtain the "Filters > Enhance > Noise reduction" tool equivalent in Python-Fu that is doing a very good job to finalise the cleaning of the inline contours hot pixels (see below an example of the split view). The filter is very efficient in reestablishing the curve smoothness and killing the hot pixels.

[image: Split-view of the Filter>Enhance>Noise Reduction]

Does anyone know if the method exists or if there is a way to implement an equivalent (I already tried plug-in-blur which is very bad) ?